# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code gives me an error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" on line:

```
"$("#mainPage").load('pages/' . name . '.php');"
```

why? should i show the entire page code?

```
$("#mainPage").fadeTo(500, 0, function() {
    name = $(button).attr('name');
    $("#mainPage").load('pages/' . name . '.php');
    var page = "pages/" .name. ".php";
    var state = {
      "canBeAnything": true
    };

    history.pushState(state, "new Page", "main.php?page="+page);
});
```

Comment: `+` is concatenation operator in Javascript, as against `.` in php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript uses `+` for concatenation, not `.`

Additionally, you should use `var name = ...` instead of just `name = ...` to avoid creating a global!

Answer (score 3):

You used PHP style concatenation, instead of Javascript style for that line.

```
$("#mainPage").load('pages/' + name + '.php');
```