# Adding JavaScript to a php script

Tags: javascript, alert, confirm

I have written a php script to act as a live search of database tables, so it requires that the HTML is written as a part of the php script. I need to add some JavaScript so that when I want to delete a certain element from a database table it prompts me to confirm the deletion.

This is what I am going for, however when I run the script it gives me an unexpected string error:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$output .= '<tbody>   
    <tr> 
        <td>'.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['address'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['id_num'].'</td>
        <td>
            <a class="edittablebtn" href="employees_database_page.php?edit_employee='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-cog" style="padding:5px;"></i></a>     
            <a class="edittablebtn"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="padding:5px;"></i></a>                 
            <a class="deltablebtn" onclick="return confirm('You are about to remove this analysis from client ordering selection.\nAre you sure you want to continue?');" href="employees_database_page.php?del_employee='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-user-times" style="padding:5px;"></i></a>       
        </td> 
    </tr>    
</tbody>';          
}

echo $output;
```

The JavaScript is added inline at the `deltablebtn` class. The JavaScript code is as follows:

```
onclick="return confirm('You are about to remove this analysis from client ordering selection.\nAre you sure you want to continue?');"
```

Comment: A.) That isn't jQuery, it's JavaScript. 2.) If you're going to use jQuery you do not need inline JavaScript.

Comment: Can you try this: `onclick="return confirm(\'You are about to remove this analysis from client ordering selection.\nAre you sure you want to continue?\');"`

Comment: That worked thanks. Make it an answer so that I can accept the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232394/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape quotes in your JavaScript expression. So change this line:

```
onclick="return confirm('You are about to remove this analysis from client ordering selection.\nAre you sure you want to continue?');"
```

to:

```
onclick="return confirm(\'You are about to remove this analysis from client ordering selection.\nAre you sure you want to continue?\');"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write an extra Javascript function, and then delete the ID with an ajax request.

```
<script>
    function delItem(id){

        if(confirm("Really sure to delete.....?")){

        //ajax request to URL: employees_database_page.php?del_employee=id (id from function param)
            var delUrl = "employees_database_page.php?del_employee="+id
        }
    }
</script>
```

For the ajax request, I suggest to use jQuery, cause it's much more easier.
With Javascript, ajax request should me made as in this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Within in the php-code you have to define the onclick method, with the ID as parameter:

```
echo '<a class="deltablebtn" onclick="delItem('.$row['id'].')"><i class="fa fa-user-times" style="padding:5px;"></i></a>';
```